# R qqplot argument "y" is missing error

Tags: r, plot, quantile

I am relatively new to R and I am struggling with a error messages related to `qqplot`.  Some sample data are at the bottom.  I am trying to do a `qqplot` on some azimuth data, i.e. like compass directions.  I've looked around here and the `?qqplot` R documentation, but I don't see a solution I can understand in either.  I don't understand the syntax for the function or the format the data are supposed to be in, or probably both.  I First I tried loading the data as a single column of values, i.e. just the "Azimuth" column.

```
azimuth <- read.csv(file.choose(), header=TRUE)
qqplot(azimuth$Azimuth)
```

returns the following error,

```
Error in sort(y) : argument "y" is missing, with no default
```

Then I tried including the corresponding dip angles along with the azimuth data and received the same error.  I also tried,

```
qqnorm(azimuth)
```

but this returned the following error,

```
Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : 
'x' and 'y' lengths differ
```

Dataframe "azimuth":

```
    Azimuth        Altitude
23.33211466    -6.561729793
31.51267873     4.801537153
29.04577711      5.24504954
23.63450905     14.03342708
29.12535459     7.224141678
20.76972007     47.95686329
54.89253987     4.837417689
56.57958227     13.12587996
13.09845182    -7.417776178
26.45155154     31.83546988
29.15718557     25.47767069
28.09084746     14.61603384
28.93436865    -1.641785416
28.77521371     17.30536039
29.58690392    -2.202076058
0.779859221     12.92044019
 27.1359178     12.20305106
23.57084707     11.97925859
28.99803063     3.931326877
```

`dput()` version:

```
azimuth <- 
structure(list(Azimuth = c(23.33211466, 31.51267873, 29.04577711, 
23.63450905, 29.12535459, 20.76972007, 54.89253987, 56.57958227, 
13.09845182, 26.45155154, 29.15718557, 28.09084746, 28.93436865, 
28.77521371, 29.58690392, 0.779859221, 27.1359178, 23.57084707, 
28.99803063), Altitude = c(-6.561729793, 4.801537153, 5.24504954, 
14.03342708, 7.224141678, 47.95686329, 4.837417689, 13.12587996, 
-7.417776178, 31.83546988, 25.47767069, 14.61603384, -1.641785416, 
17.30536039, -2.202076058, 12.92044019, 12.20305106, 11.97925859, 
3.931326877)), .Names = c("Azimuth", "Altitude"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -19L))
```

Comment: The easiest with a data.frame is `with(azimuth, qqplot(Azimuth, Altitude))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the `qqplot` function takes two input parameters, `x` and `y` as follows:

```
qqplot(x, y, plot.it = TRUE, xlab = "your x-axis label", ylab="your y-axis label", ...)
```

When you made your call as given above, you only gave one vector, hence R complained the `y` argument was missing.  Check you input data set and see if you can find what `x` and `y` should be for your call to `qqplot`.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

`qqPlot`

with a capital `P`.

Comment: Great suggestion @user10381916, thanks! Note that qq**P**lot (capital *P*) comes from the `car` package.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you want to create the graph.

Have you ever tried?

```
qqnorm(azimuth$Azimuth);qqline(azimuth$Azimuth)
```